# Suitescript 2.0 - Possible to hide a field group?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a suitescript that hides all fields in a field group if an option is selected but I would also like to hide the fieldgroup that these fields were under.

Is there a way to also hide the fieldgroup?

Answer (score 1):

No, the only way is to hide all the fields within the group.

I would suggest it may be quicker/more efficient perhaps to use a workflow to hide the fields on field change action.

Comment: I can hide all of the fields in the group using a suitescript 2.0 but the title of the field group still appears. I was under the impression if there were no fields displayed in a field group the field group title would not display but guess I was incorrect with that assumption.

Comment: @penone did you achieve this,if yes how?

Comment: @MUHAMMADMUBUSHERASLAM Nope. Never was able to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

You can hide fields using suitescript 2.0 beforeLoad function and also use jQuery to hide the label for field group.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).